# Is it possible to read file locally inside procedure?

Tags: maple

If I do this

```
u:=1;
save u, "test.txt";
u:=2:
```

then

```
test1:=proc() local u;
  read "test.txt";
end proc:
test1():
'u'=u;
                      u = 1
```

So, when reading a file inside a procedure the variable `u` was assigned globally. Is it possible to make sure it stays local?

EDIT: The goal for procedure test1() is to do some stuff, which needs variables with values from a file. That file was made after some long lasting calculation, which was made in some other work. In order to avoid errors I need to make sure that test1() won't change the values of variables in my current work since names can be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks the context of what you're trying to accomplish with `test1`, and why you feel the need for a convoluted mechanism.

Ie, why don't you simply supply the assigned `u` as one of the arguments passed to `test1`?

Here are two alternatives, for which any subsequent call/invocation of `test1` doesn't result in the global name `u` being reassigned. These both result in procedures where that value is actually part of the procedure body.

Here's the first alternative,

```
restart;
test1proto := proc() local u;
    u := __dummyu;
end proc:

u := 1:

test1 := subs(__dummyu = u,
              eval(test1proto)):
u:='u':

test1();

           1

'u'=u; # global u is still unassigned

         u = u
```

In that way you can "shoehorn" any value you want (including, say, a running value of `u` at the higher level) into `test1` so that its local `u` attains that value. You can also repeat that `subs` call, to instantiate the template procedure again at other values.

Note that this mechanism can replace a dummy name in the template procedure without your necessarily having assigned to `u`. Ie,

```
restart;
test1proto := proc() local u;
    u := __dummyu;
end proc:

test1 := subs(__dummyu = 1,
              eval(test1proto));

     test1 := proc () local u; u := 1 end proc

test1();

           1

'u'=u; # global u was never unassigned

         u = u
```

You can make that kind of `subs` call and substitute whatever you want for the dummy name.

Here's another alternative, in which the source of the `test1` procedure is also in its own text file. That source file for `test1`, which I've named "test1.mpl" looks like this, say,

```
test1 := proc() local u;
$include "u.mm"
end proc:
```

Now, in my Maple session,

```
restart;
u := 1:
save u, "u.mm";
u:='u':

read "test1.mpl"

print(eval(test1));

     proc () local u; u := 1 end proc

test1();

           1

'u'=u; # global u is still unassigned

          u = u
```

Here again you can `save` futher, different values for `u`, and then once again `read` the source file "test1.mpl" and get different procedures with different values.

Note that I still suspect that your actual goals (as yet unclear in full) might be accomplished with mechanisms simpler than any of this. But exactly how you intend on using `test1`, and any restrictions of your programmatic flow, are unknown.

Comment: Added more info to the question. Also changed the u:='u': to u:=2: to make it clear that the point is that the variable shouldn't change its value (or stay unassigned).